# How do I unminify a DXF file that appears to be minified?

Tags: cad, cnc

I have tried so many different programs to convert this file to correct, but what I have is a DXF of an eagle. It appears to be minified in some fashion or created in some non-standard CAD program. There are supposed to be carriage returns after each keyword, but the entire file shows as the below; all of it on a single line. Fusion 360, FreeCad, LibreCad, 15+ online converters, all can't read it. Carveco, Inkscape, and a number of other programs won't read it. I even tried Sketchup to no avail.

The file is from: https://www.cnccookbook.com/holiday-art-vector-dxf-cnc/

The code for the file: https://cnccookbook.com/wp-content/uploads/Freebies/dxf-downloads/Eagle-Decal.dxf

Any assistance in this matter would be absolutely wonderful.

```
0 SECTION 2 HEADER 9 $EXTMIN 10 1.243011 20 0.376850 9 $EXTMAX 10 67.417427 20 30.281479 0 ENDSEC 0 SECTION 2 TABLES 0 TABLE 2 LTYPE 70 1 0 LTYPE 2 0 70 0 3 Solid Line 72 65 73 0 40 0.0 0 ENDTAB 0 TABLE 2 LAYER 70 1 0 LAYER 2 1 70 0 62 7 6 0 0 ENDTAB 0 ENDSEC 0 SECTION 2 BLOCKS 0 ENDSEC 0 SECTION 2 ENTITIES 0 POLYLINE 8 1 66 1 70 1 0 VERTEX 8 1 10 4.719383 20 10.810471 42 -0.404218 0
```

Comment: I downloaded the file and was able to open it in FastCAD, Libre Office Draw and Inkscape 1.2 without difficulty. Each line ends with `CR LF` and there are no start and end apostrophes as you have shown them. (If you're trying to create preformatted markdown text then you need to use backticks ```, not apostrophes, and they need to be on lines by themselves.)

Comment: Problem is likely in your download method. Browser may be trying to do things it should not.  See if you can right click and "save target as" or "save link as"

Comment: "curl "https://cnccookbook.com/wp-content/uploads/Freebies/dxf-downloads/Eagle-Decal.dxf" -o eagle.dxf" looks like this does the trick. Thx for the pointers.